# Memoir + minitoc: "Chapter N" disappears from heading due to mtcpatchmem

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, minitoc

I'm using `memoir` with `minitoc`. Everythings seems to work fine except that I get this

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{mtcpatchmem}
\chapterstyle{default}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\chapter{Introduccion}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Instead of this:

[image]

The swicht happens when I add/remove the line

```
\usepackage{mtcpatchmem}
```

which is the patch that makes `memoir`  and  `minitoc` compatible.

Is  this normal? How can I get back to the original behaviour that includes "Chapter N" at the heading of each chapter?

Comment: Assuming you have an up-to-date TeX distribution (e.g. not really older than two years etc. you should not need `mtcpatchmem` any longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `minitoc` manual (current version from 2015/07/13) states on page, that `mtcpatchmem` is not needed any longer for a reasonably new version of `memoir` (although it does not really specify which is the last version that needed the patch)

`memoir` itself has been updated both in 2015 and in 2016.

The easiest solution is: Omit `\usepackage{mtcpatchmem}` ;-)

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{minitoc}
%\usepackage{mtcpatchmem}
\dominitoc
\chapterstyle{default}
\begin{document}
\faketableofcontents
\title{Title}
\chapter{Introduccion}
\minitoc
\section{Foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Side note: I just realized that the original author and maintainer of `minitoc`, J. P. Drucbert passed away in 2009 -- I was unaware of this :-(
This explains why `minitoc` was (and still is) not maintained for so many years now.

Comment: Thanks Christian. If I remove the usepackage then other thinks break (tocs at the beginning of chapters). I thought the version TeX 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) was recent enough, I'll try to update it !

Comment: @alberto: There was an update to `memoir` last year and this year too, I think updating the whole TL is much easier than patch `mtcpatchmem`

Comment: Texmaker updated and now works like a charm !

Comment: I have gone with etoc package and it works great!